# stringbyevaluatingjavascriptstring from drop down

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I´m trying to fetch the values from a html drop down using a webview which is populated with a segmented controller.

Anyone know how to enter an

```
 NSString *string [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsBy
```

for the following html code and to select one of the option values

```
<div id="loginselect" style="clear:both:">
            <select name="usertype" size="1"  id="usertype" class="select1" >     
<option value="0"  selected="selected">Staff</option>
<option value="1" >Student</option>
<option value="2" >Parent</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementByID('usertype').value
```

Comment: but how can I specify the value and make it selected?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from sixthcent gave the right answer. I just had to add the value like this:

```
document.getElementById('usertype').value='1'
```